# How can I slowdown only the bullet when shooting?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Shooting : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private Transform[] firePoints;
    [SerializeField]
    private Rigidbody projectilePrefab;
    [SerializeField]
    private float launchForce = 700f;
    [SerializeField]
    private Animator anim;
    [SerializeField]
    private bool automaticFire = false;
    [SerializeField]
    private bool slowDownEffect = false;

    private bool coroutineEnded = false;

    private void Start()
    {
        anim.SetBool("Shooting", true);
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        if (isAnimationStatePlaying(anim, 0, "AIMING") == true)
        {
            if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1") && automaticFire == false)
            {
                if (anim.GetBool("Shooting") == true)
                {
                    anim.Play("SHOOTING");
                    LaunchProjectile();
                }
            }
            else if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1") && automaticFire == true)
            {
                automaticFire = false;
            }
            else
            {
                if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire2"))
                {
                    automaticFire = true;
                }
                if (automaticFire == true)
                {
                    anim.Play("SHOOTING");
                    LaunchProjectile();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void LaunchProjectile()
    {
        foreach (var firePoint in firePoints)
        {
            Rigidbody projectileInstance = Instantiate(
                projectilePrefab,
                firePoint.position,
                firePoint.rotation);

            projectileInstance.AddForce(new Vector3(0, 0, 1) * launchForce);
            StartCoroutine(AddDrag(5, 5, projectileInstance));

            if (coroutineEnded == true)
            {
                projectileInstance.gameObject.AddComponent<BulletDestruction>().Init();
            }
        }
    }

    IEnumerator AddDrag(float maxDrag, float mul, Rigidbody rb)
    {

        float current_drag = 0;

        while (current_drag < maxDrag)
        {
            current_drag += Time.deltaTime * mul;
            rb.drag = current_drag;
            yield return null;
        }

        rb.velocity = Vector3.zero;
        rb.angularVelocity = Vector3.zero;
        rb.drag = 0;

        coroutineEnded = true;
    }

    bool isAnimationStatePlaying(Animator anim, int animLayer, string stateName)
    {
        if (anim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(animLayer).IsName(stateName))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

I tried to use StartCoroutine to add Drag. The problem is that it's shooting the first buulet and the first bullet kind of slowdown and stop in the end and then when trying to fire the next bullet I'm getting exception :

MissingReferenceException: The object of type 'Rigidbody' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it.

On the line :

```
rb.drag = current_drag;
```

And I'm not sure if adding drag is the right way and what values should I give in. I tried 5 and 5.

The idea is to slowdown only the bullets like slowdown effect.

I did a script for the slowdowns :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SlowDown : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Overall Slowdown")]
    [Range(0,1f)]
    public float overallSlowdown = 1f;
    [Space(5)]
    [Header("Bullet Time")]
    [Range(0, 50)]
    public float bulletTime = 0.25f;

    private void Update()
    {
        Time.timeScale = overallSlowdown;
    }
}
```

But timeScale slowdown the whole game and I want also to be able to slowdown only the bullets.

Comment: I'd guess your MissingReferenceException is the coroutineEnded flag. The first bullet gets processed then sets the flag, so when you fire a second bullet it gets immediately destroyed by the `if (coroutineEnded)` block because coroutineEnded is still true. And that doesn't work how you meant it anyway: the `if` is executed immediately after you've queued the coroutine for background execution, not when the coroutine completes. I'd delete all the coroutineEnded stuff for now and worry about that later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## If you want something to happen at the end of a coroutine, put it at the end of the coroutine

```
private void LaunchProjectile()
{
    foreach (var firePoint in firePoints)
    {
        Rigidbody projectileInstance = Instantiate(
            projectilePrefab,
            firePoint.position,
            firePoint.rotation);

        projectileInstance.AddForce(new Vector3(0, 0, 1) * launchForce);
        StartCoroutine(AddDrag(5, 5, projectileInstance));
    }
}

IEnumerator AddDrag(float maxDrag, float mul, Rigidbody rb)
{
    float current_drag = 0;

    while (current_drag < maxDrag)
    {
        current_drag += Time.deltaTime * mul;
        rb.drag = current_drag;
        yield return null;
    }

    rb.velocity = Vector3.zero;
    rb.angularVelocity = Vector3.zero;
    rb.drag = 0;

    rb.gameObject.AddComponent<BulletDestruction>().Init();
}
```

Calling `StartCoroutine()` does not halt the execution of the method it is in, so "waiting for the coroutine to finish" outside of that coroutine method makes no sense (as there may be multiple copies of that coroutine!)

The only logical place to wait for a coroutine to finish is either inside another coroutine or inside the method you're waiting on. As the object you are wanting to modify is passed to the coroutine, inserting the desired logic into the coroutine method is a logical choice.